# Inno setup file execution in Windows Server 2012R2 not working

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I am trying to install SQL Server through inno setup in Windows Server 2012R2 machine which fails with exit code "Process exit code: 1".

The same setup is **working fine** in Windows 2008R2 and Windows 7 machines. I am not getting any error prompt for the failure. When the Executable file is called with parameters, the setup terminates. The log snippet is available below.

```
2015-07-15 16:47:38.734   Run as: Current user
2015-07-15 16:47:38.734   Type: Exec
2015-07-15 16:47:38.734   Filename: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\is-4IUN9.tmp\dbs-server\DBS Server Setup.exe
2015-07-15 16:47:38.734   Parameters: /dir="D:\Install.Folder" /dbsapwd=123_Admin /MSSQLServerSetupFile="F:\setup.exe" /MSSQLServerSPSetupFile="G:\SQLServer2008R2SP3-KB123456-x64-ENU.exe" /MSSQLServerLicense="AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE" /dbinstancename="ABC_SYSTEMS" /MSSQLServerSelection="SQL Server 2008R2" /silent /restart=false
2015-07-15 16:47:42.609   Process exit code: 1
2015-07-15 16:47:42.609   Need to restart Windows? Yes
2015-07-15 16:47:45.344   Will not restart Windows automatically.
```

I believe it has something to do with how the parameters is passed. Could anyone suggest?

Thanks in Advance,

DeeJay.

Comment: You might dump SQL Server installation log file to see the exact error.

Comment: @LexLi, the Server installation has not even started and there is no SQL Server installation log created yet. The only piece of log is the snippet I ve added in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue at last. SQL Server required .NET Framework 3.5 as a pre-requisite which is not available by default in the Windows Server 2012 R2. So after installing the same, the SQL Server was installed properly.

The following link helped!!!

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn482071.aspx